# python: iterating over a changing dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

There are plenty of questions regarding iterating over changing dictionaries, but I'm working over a strange case:

I have a dictionary (specifically `kwargs`) that will contain key value pairs used to define an object.  The object's fields may have subfields.  So here's an example:

```
kwargs = {'field1':1,
          'field2':2,
          'field3.a':31,
          'field3.b':32,
          'field3.c':33,
          'field4':4}
```

The issue is when I process, I need to process all of field3 at once, and ensure that all are present at that time.  So here's an example of what I need to do:

```
if key.startswith('field3'):
    assert 'field3.a' in kwargs
    assert 'field3.b' in kwargs
    assert 'field3.c' in kwargs
    a = kwargs.pop('field3.a')
    b = kwargs.pop('field3.b')
    c = kwargs.pop('field3.c')
    str = 'a: %s b:%s c:%s' % (a,b,c)
    results.append(str)
```

The issue is this can't be in a loop over `kwargs.keys()` or `kwargs.iteritems()`, because I will remove the fields and then later try to access them.  I suppose I could start the loop with

```
for k in kwargs.keys():
    if k in kwargs:
        #blah
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to solve this.

Comment: How about changing the structure of your dictionary to `{…, 'field3': {'a': 31, 'b': 32, 'c': 33}, …}`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach That would be ideal, but unfortunately I can't do that.  it's a requirement of how the input will be received.  If you're interested, the reason is it's ultimately going it be a [robot](http://robotframework.org/) keyword, which needs to mirror a proprietary CLI.  This is how the CLI takes its input, so it's also how I need to

Comment: ewok: You can always flatten the dictionary right before passing it on to the CLI, which might be less pain than doing the processing with a broken data structure all along.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm not actually using the CLI.  I am writing a Robot library that will be used by the same people who use the CLI.  For usability, My Robot library needs to look the same as the CLI from the user's perspective. Changing the format of the input is not an option, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the job into steps. In first step, you collect all fields into a new dictionary.

For example:

```
fields = defaultdict(dict)
for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
    if '.' in key:
        field, subkey = key.split('.', 1)
    else:
        field, subkey = key, ''
    fields[field][subkey] = value
```

Now you have something like this in `fields`:

```
{'field1': {'': 1},
 'field2': {'': 2},
 'field3': {'a': 31, 'c': 33, 'b': 32},
 'field4': {'': 4}}
```

From that point on, it should be easier to process data the way you wanted.